# Exception while trying to select a customer to launch asm session in customersupportbackoffice

Tags: migration, sap-commerce-cloud

We are migrating from hybris 6.3 to hybris 1811. While trying to select a customer in customer support backoffice and launch asm session. Console throws an error because of which we are not able to launch asm for any customer.

Seems like some savedCarts qualifier is missing. Could not figure out where it was used.

the exception throws is :

> ''' DefaultEditorAreaPanelRenderer] No attribute with qualifier
>   savedCarts found.
>   de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.exceptions.UnknownIdentifierException:
>   No attribute with qualifier savedCarts found.
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.type.impl.DefaultTypeService.getAttributeDescriptor(DefaultTypeService.java:201)
>   ~[coreserver.jar:?]
>           at com.hybris.backoffice.cockpitng.dataaccess.facades.type.DefaultPlatformTypeFacadeStrategy.getAttributeDescription(DefaultPlatformTypeFacadeStrategy.java:717)
>   ~[classes/:?]
>           at com.hybris.cockpitng.dataaccess.facades.type.impl.DefaultTypeFacade.getAttributeDescription(DefaultTypeFacade.java:90)
>   ~[cockpit-data-integration-18.11.1-RC1.jar:?]
>           at com.hybris.cockpitng.dataaccess.facades.type.impl.DefaultTypeFacade.getAttributeDescription(DefaultTypeFacade.java:79)
>   ~[cockpit-data-integration-18.11.1-RC1.jar:?]
>           at com.hybris.cockpitng.labels.impl.TypeQualifierStringObjectHandler.getObjectDescription(TypeQualifierStringObjectHandler.java:274)
>   ~[cockpit-data-integration-18.11.1-RC1.jar:?]
>           at com.hybris.cockpitng.labels.impl.DefaultLabelService.getObjectDescription(DefaultLabelService.java:139)
>   ~[cockpitcore-18.11.1-RC1.jar:?]
>           at com.hybris.cockpitng.labels.impl.TypeAwareLabelService.getObjectDescription(TypeAwareLabelService.java:45)
>   ~[cockpit-data-integration-18.11.1-RC1.jar:?]
>           at com.hybris.cockpitng.common.EditorConfigurator.getAttributeDescription(EditorConfigurator.java:269)
>   ~[backoffice-widgets-18.11.1-RC1.jar:?]
>           at com.hybris.cockpitng.common.EditorConfigurator.configure(EditorConfigurator.java:428)
>   ~[backoffice-widgets-18.11.1-RC1.jar:?]
>           at com.hybris.cockpitng.common.EditorConfigurator.configure(EditorConfigurator.java:450)
>   ~[backoffice-widgets-18.11.1-RC1.jar:?]
>           at com.hybris.cockpitng.common.EditorBuilder.configure(EditorBuilder.java:294)
>   ~[backoffice-widgets-18.11.1-RC1.jar:?]
>           at com.hybris.cockpitng.widgets.editorarea.renderer.impl.AbstractEditorAreaComponentRenderer.createEditor(AbstractEditorAreaComponentRenderer.java:297)
>   ~[backoffice-widgets-18.11.1-RC1.jar:?]
>           at com.hybris.cockpitng.widgets.editorarea.renderer.impl.DefaultEditorAreaPanelRenderer$2.render(DefaultEditorAreaPanelRenderer.java:171)
>   ~[backoffice-widgets-18.11.1-RC1.jar:?]
>           at com.hybris.cockpitng.widgets.editorarea.renderer.impl.DefaultEditorAreaPanelRenderer$2.render(DefaultEditorAreaPanelRenderer.java:163)
>   ~[backoffice-widgets-18.11.1-RC1.jar:?]
>           at com.hybris.cockpitng.widgets.common.ProxyRenderer.render(ProxyRenderer.java:93)
>   ~[backoffice-widgets-18.11.1-RC1.jar:?]
>           at com.hybris.cockpitng.widgets.editorarea.renderer.impl.DefaultEditorAreaPanelRenderer$1.render(DefaultEditorAreaPanelRenderer.java:130)
>   ~[backoffice-widgets-18.11.1-RC1.jar:?]
>           at com.hybris.cockpitng.widgets.editorarea.renderer.impl.DefaultEditorAreaPanelRenderer$1.render(DefaultEditorAreaPanelRenderer.java:114)
>   ~[backoffice-widgets-18.11.1-RC1.jar:?]
>           at com.hybris.cockpitng.widgets.common.ProxyRenderer.render(ProxyRenderer.java:93)
>   ~[backoffice-widgets-18.11.1-RC1.jar:?]
>           at com.hybris.cockpitng.widgets.editorarea.renderer.impl.DefaultEditorAreaPanelRenderer.render(DefaultEditorAreaPanelRenderer.java:95)
>   ~[backoffice-widgets-18.11.1-RC1.jar:?]
>           at com.hybris.cockpitng.widgets.editorarea.renderer.impl.DefaultEditorAreaPanelRenderer.render(DefaultEditorAreaPanelRenderer.java:44)
>   ~[backoffice-widgets-18.11.1-RC1.jar:?]
>           at com.hybris.cockpitng.widgets.common.ProxyRenderer.render(ProxyRenderer.java:93)
>   ~[backoffice-widgets-18.11.1-RC1.jar:?]
>           at com.hybris.cockpitng.widgets.editorarea.renderer.impl.DefaultEditorAreaSectionRenderer.renderAttributesInPanels(DefaultEditorAreaSectionRenderer.java:379)
>   ~[backoffice-widgets-18.11.1-RC1.jar:?]
>           at com.hybris.cockpitng.widgets.editorarea.renderer.impl.DefaultEditorAreaSectionRenderer$2.render(DefaultEditorAreaSectionRenderer.java:271)
>   ~[backoffice-widgets-18.11.1-RC1.jar:?]
>           at com.hybris.cockpitng.widgets.editorarea.renderer.impl.DefaultEditorAreaSectionRenderer$2.render(DefaultEditorAreaSectionRenderer.java:259)
>   ~[backoffice-widgets-18.11.1-RC1.jar:?]
>           at com.hybris.cockpitng.widgets.common.ProxyRenderer.render(ProxyRenderer.java:93)
>   ~[backoffice-widgets-18.11.1-RC1.jar:?]
>           at com.hybris.cockpitng.widgets.editorarea.renderer.impl.DefaultEditorAreaSectionRenderer.render(DefaultEditorAreaSectionRenderer.java:122)
>   ~[backoffice-widgets-18.11.1-RC1.jar:?]
>           at com.hybris.cockpitng.widgets.editorarea.renderer.impl.DefaultEditorAreaSectionRenderer.render(DefaultEditorAreaSectionRenderer.java:68)
>   ~[backoffice-widgets-18.11.1-RC1.jar:?]
>           at com.hybris.cockpitng.widgets.common.ProxyRenderer.render(ProxyRenderer.java:93)
>   ~[backoffice-widgets-18.11.1-RC1.jar:?]
>           at com.hybris.cockpitng.widgets.editorarea.renderer.impl.DefaultEditorAreaTabRenderer.render(DefaultEditorAreaTabRenderer.java:73)
>   ~[backoffice-widgets-18.11.1-RC1.jar:?]
>           at com.hybris.cockpitng.widgets.editorarea.renderer.impl.DefaultEditorAreaTabRenderer.render(DefaultEditorAreaTabRenderer.java:31)
>   ~[backoffice-widgets-18.11.1-RC1.jar:?]
>           at com.hybris.cockpitng.widgets.common.ProxyRenderer.render(ProxyRenderer.java:93)
>   ~[backoffice-widgets-18.11.1-RC1.jar:?]
>           at com.hybris.cockpitng.widgets.editorarea.renderer.impl.DefaultEditorAreaRenderer.lambda$render$0(DefaultEditorAreaRenderer.java:128)
>   ~[backoffice-widgets-18.11.1-RC1.jar:?]
>           at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.onEvent(AbstractComponent.java:3168)
>   ~[zk-8.5.1.2.jar:3.6.4]
>           at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.service(AbstractComponent.java:3138)
>   ~[zk-8.5.1.2.jar:3.6.4]
>           at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.service(AbstractComponent.java:3080)
>   ~[zk-8.5.1.2.jar:3.6.4]
>           at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessor.process(EventProcessor.java:138)
>   ~[zk-8.5.1.2.jar:3.6.4]
>           at org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.Events.sendEvent(Events.java:343) ~[zk-8.5.1.2.jar:3.6.4]
>           at org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.Events.sendEvent(Events.java:367) ~[zk-8.5.1.2.jar:3.6.4]
>           at org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.Events.sendEvent(Events.java:375) ~[zk-8.5.1.2.jar:3.6.4]
>           at com.hybris.cockpitng.widgets.editorarea.renderer.impl.DefaultEditorAreaRenderer.sendRenderEvent(DefaultEditorAreaRenderer.java:262)
>   ~[backoffice-widgets-18.11.1-RC1.jar:?]
>           at com.hybris.cockpitng.widgets.editorarea.renderer.impl.DefaultEditorAreaRenderer.render(DefaultEditorAreaRenderer.java:167)
>   ~[backoffice-widgets-18.11.1-RC1.jar:?] '''

Comment: did you try to update running system ?

Comment: you should reset your backoffice configuration. it seems like you are trying to access a non existing property via backoffice definition.

Comment: Hi please update your system by selecting backoffice extension and if you have customer back-office extension please select them also then please reset backoffice perspective.
To reset perspective :
1. Press F4 than in the right corner you will have to reset everything option once you do the reset then press F4 again.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause: there is no such attribute in the system for the Customer type.

One of the possible solutions is to exclude "savedCarts" attribute from the Bulk Edit Wizard. See the Backoffice configuration below:

```
<context type="Customer" merge-by="type" component="bulk-edit-wizard">
    <wz:flow id="bulkEditWizard" title="bulkedit.wizard.title" size="large">
        <wz:step id="step1" label="bulkedit.wizard.step.select.attributes" sublabel="bulkedit.wizard.step.select.sublabel">
            <wz:content id="step1.content">
                <wz:custom-view id="attributesSelector" lang="zul" merge-mode="replace">
                    <wz:renderer spring-bean="bulkEditAttributesSelectorRenderer">
                        <wz:parameter>
                            <wz:name>bulkEditFormModelKey</wz:name>
                            <wz:value>bulkEditForm</wz:value>
                        </wz:parameter>
                        <wz:parameter>
                            <wz:name>excludedQualifiers</wz:name>
                            <wz:value>savedCarts,modifiedtime</wz:value>
                        </wz:parameter>
                    </wz:renderer>
                </wz:custom-view>
            </wz:content>
            <wz:navigation>
                <wz:cancel/>
                <wz:next visible="bulkEditForm.attributesForm.chosenAttributes?.size()>0"/>
            </wz:navigation>
        </wz:step>
    </wz:flow>
</context>
```